# Is it a good idea to destroy sockets after a single use?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I've been looking into making a simple Sockets-based game in Java, and read in multiple places that client sockets are destroyed after a single exchange. Is this good practice for continued connections? The server needs to maintain a connection with a client (i.e. not using socket.accept() every time it wants to tell a client about something), but can't wait every time for the client's response. I already have the server/client running in separate threads, but won't destroying the socket after every exchange mean re-acquiring (or failing to re-acquire) a connection to that client? I've seen so many conflicting websites about sockets in Java and how they should be implemented.

Comment: Your question is too broad. You should describe a concrete problem that you have. If a client needs a constant connection to a server, it usually doesn't close that connection. Closing and reopening a connection can take a considerable amount of time and slow things down. In other circumstances it might make sense to close connections or use a different protocol that doesn't require connections like UDP.

Comment: It depends. Programming practice / Java has few models to use sockets, from pool, to server library (i.e. programmer have not to do with raw socket) and few more. Some have very good optimalisation. What is Your scenario of use?

Comment: Socket-per-request saves you from a whole class of errors (timeouts, keepalives, client-server out-of-sync) but comes at the cost of throughput. The time to establish a connection can be significant and the TCP performance optimising algorithms will have to start from scratch again each time you create a new socket.

Answer (score -1):

There's no hard and fast rules, but it does depend slightly on what data rates you want to achieve.

For example, YouTube is a streaming video service, but the video data is delivered by means of the client using https to fetch batches of video data. Inefficient, yes, but very easy to program for. There's lots of reasons to use https for an application like YouTube (firewalls, etc), but ultimate power saving and network performance were not one of them. The "proper" way would be to use a protocol like RTP which uses UDP to deliver small packets of data which can then be rearranged into order, you also have to deal with missing frames at the CODEC level, etc. Much less network traffic, friendly to bandwidth constrained network links, but significantly more difficult to deal with traversing across firewalls, in client software, etc.

So if your game is sending modest amounts of data, the only thing wrong with setting up and tearing down a whole socket connection for every message is the nagging feeling you yourself will have that it is somehow not the most efficient solution.

Though it sounds like you have a conflict between the need to communicate between client / server and a need to process something else whilst waiting for the communication to complete. Here you're getting into asynchronous I/O territory. To make that easy i strongly suggest you take a look at ZeroMQ - that will make everything a whole lot simpler.

Comment: The 'only thing wrong' is that it *isn't* the most efficient solution. No 'nagging feeling' or 'somehow' about it. It wastes seven packet exchanges per message.

Comment: @EJP, since when was the number of packets exchanged ever chosen as the sole and inviolable measure of "efficiency"? And since when was a bit of extra traffic "wrong"?Efficiency and rightness means different things to different people, and most have long since stopped worrying about trying to reduce network traffic to the lowest possible level; life's too short.

Comment: @bazze Nobody said anything about 'sole and inviolable', but since when is extra traffic not less efficient than no extra traffic? And since when when did anybody's feelings have anything to do with it? Given the enormous effort that went into HTTP keepalive your final comment is clearly untrue.

Comment: @EJP, I refer you to your first comment. You may be fixated on minimising network traffic, but many other people may care less about network traffic (especially if the data rate is much less than their network bandwidth) and are often more interested in getting an application running for the least amount of manpower, that being their definition of efficiency. That's the essence of most development done today. What's the point of excess network bandwidth if you don't use it to make the programmer's job a lot easier / quicker?

Answer (score -1):

> and read in multiple places that client sockets are destroyed after a single exchange.

Only in the places where that actually happens. There are numerous contexts where it doesn't, the outstanding example being HTTP, where every effort is made to reuse connections.

> Is this good practice for continued connections?

The question is a contradiction in terms. A continued connection is a connection that isn't closed. A closed connection can't be continued.

> The server needs to maintain a connection with a client (i.e. not using socket.accept() every time it wants to tell a client about something), but can't wait every time for the client's response.

The word you are groping for here is 'session'.

> I already have the server/client running in separate threads, but won't destroying the socket after every exchange mean re-acquiring (or failing to re-acquire) a connection to that client?

Yes.

> I've seen so many conflicting websites about sockets in Java and how they should be implemented.

You should use a connection pool at the client; a request loop at the server that looks for multiple requests per connection; a client-side facility that closes idle connections after some idle timeout; and a read timeout at the server that closes connections on which no request has been read within the timeout.